# How to address nested array keys after grouping in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have table called sales like this:

```
id    customer_id    product_id    sales
1        4           190            100
2        4           190            150
3        4           191            200
4        5           192            300
5        6           200            400
```

What I'd like to do is, get a total on how many of each products have been bought by a customer. Therefor I perform a simple group by:

```
Sales.all.group(:customer_id, product_id).sum(:sales)
```

What this gives me is a hash with keys consisting of arrays with the combination of customer_id and product_id:

```
hash = {
  [4, 190] => 250,
  [4, 191] => 200,
  [5, 192] => 300,
  [6, 200] => 400
}
```

While this gives me the result, I'm now also looking to get the total sum of sales for each customer. I could of course write another query, but this feels redundant. Isn't there an easy way to do find all the hash array keys that start with `[4, *]` or something?

Comment: You are right... error in my code. Will fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get this value for a single value, you could do the following:

```
hash.select{|x| x[0] == 4}.values.sum 
=> 450
```

But you could also transform the hash to a grouped one on the customer-ids.

```
hash.inject(Hash.new(0)) do |result, v| 
  # v will look like [[4, 190], 250]
  customer_id = v[0][0] 
  result[customer_id] += v[1]
  result
end
```

which you could also write as a one-liner

```
hash.inject(Hash.new(0)){|result, v| result[v[0][0]] += v[1]; result} 
=> {4=>450, 5=>700}
```

Which can be further shortened when using `each_with_object` instead of `inject` (thanks to commenter Sebastian Palma)

```
hash.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)){|v,result| result[v[0][0]] += v[1]}
```

Comment: With `each_with_object` you can get rid of the `; result` (`hash.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |v, result| result[v[0][0]] += v[1] }`)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
hash.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |(ids, value), result|
  result[ids.first] += value
end
#=> { 4 => 450, 5 => 700 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could group the resulting hash based on customer id. Then sum all the values in the group:

```
hash = {
  [4, 190] => 250,
  [4, 191] => 200,
  [5, 192] => 300,
  [6, 200] => 400
}

hash.group_by { |entry| entry.shift.first }
    .transform_values { |sums| sums.flatten.sum }
#=> {4=>450, 5=>300, 6=>400}
```

`group_by` groups the key-value pairs based on the customer id. `shift` will remove the key (leaving only the values), while `first` selects the customer id (since it is the first element in the array). This leaves you with an hash `{ 4 => [[250], [200]], 5 => [[300]], 6 => [[400]] }`.

You then flatten the groups and sum all the values to get the sum for each costomer id.

Answer (score 1):

You can try following,

```
hash.group_by { |k,v| k.first }.transform_values { |v| v.map(&:last).sum }
# => {4=>450, 5=>300, 6=>400}
```

Comment: You could shorten `v.map(&:last).sum` to `v.sum(&:last)`

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to group by ID.

```rb
hash.
  group_by { |(k, _), _| k }.
  each_with_object(Hash.new{0}) do |(k, arr), acc|
    acc[k] += arr.sum(&:last)
end

#⇒ {4=>450, 5=>700}
```